# How to access Firebase storage with Firebase cloud functions Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase cloud functions with Node.js and wanted to access the files I have stored in the Firebase storage.

`var storageRef = admin.storage().ref();
storageRef.child('path').getDownloadURL().then(x => {})`

But, unfortunately it is coming up with the error:

`TypeError: admin.storage(...).ref is not a function`

Reading around, it looks like there are some compatibility issues with Node.js and Firebase Cloud storage, although I was interested to whether I could use Firebase Cloud Storage because I was using it in Firebase Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`admin.storage()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage#storage) returns a [`Storage`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage.Storage) object, which is quite different from the regular client-side Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage.  It doesn't have the `ref()` method you are expecting.  You will need to specify a storage bucket to access.  You can reference the default bucket by calling [`admin.storage().bucket()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage.Storage#bucket).  This returns a [`Bucket`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket) object, which then has a [`file()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#file) method you can use to specify a file you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although when I do this locally using terminal, I am receiving the error: ```Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail```. My code is simply: ```admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount), databaseURL: "https://db-name.firebaseio.com" }) var bucket = admin.storage().bucket('bucket_name');```

Comment: No idea, that's a completely different problem than the one you originally posted.